# Lag spikes to router, winMTR shows conflicting results

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, performance, ping

I was trying to figure out why i kept getting lag spikes in path of exile and ran winMTR. WinMTR shows occasional spikes to my router, but when i do ping tests/tracerts using command prompt or ping plotter, they never show the same ping spikes.

The only obstruction between the wifi adapter and the router is the wall/door and the router is right outside my room. Signal strength is 40 RSSI.

Does anyone know what could be causing these spikes, and why winMTR might show different results?

Heres an example winMTR : https://pastebin.com/AGePqq1V

I have tried two different wifi adapters and the results were the same.

The router is less than a year old, practically brand new.

Comment: Try a different non-conflicting channel. It sounds like interference. There are plenty of apps/programs out there to see what the wireless channels look like. Find a channel that has the least amount of your neighbors occupying it.

Comment: Also, my is sending out more packets per second so its more likely to pick up on low level packet loss.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart: Using acrylic wi-fi i can see that my 5ghz channel is only sharing with one other network though.

Comment: What type of ISP connection is this?